# Delete button is not working for Dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a button called add every time that I want to add x products, I did a dynamic delete button. the problem is the delete button because I want to press delete button, but it won't open the confirmation if I want to delete or cancel,however if I do double click  it works but I know it's bad

```
function btn_del_product(id) {
  $('#confirm').confirm({
    text: 'are you sure you want to delete this product?',
    title: 'Confirmation required',
    confirm: function(button) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '../controllers/sales.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'id=' + id + '&boton=delete'
      }).done(function(ans) {
        view_sales();
      });
    },
    cancel: function(button) {},
    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: 'No',
    post: true,
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn-default',
  });
}
```

Comment: <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-options" id="confirm" onclick="btn_del_product('<?php echo $k ?>');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>

Comment: I have to do double click to open the modal, what's wrong with it?

Comment: because im using ajax

Comment: <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-options" id="confirm" onclick="btn_del_product('<?php echo $k ?>');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>

Comment: function btn_del_product(id){
 $('#confirm').confirm({
    text: 'are you sure you want to delete this product?',
    title: 'Confirmation required',
    confirm: function(button){
      $.ajax({
        url: '../controllers/sales.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'id='+id+'&boton=delete'
      }).done(function(ans){
        view_sales();
      });
    },cancel: function(button){
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: 'No',
    post: true,
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn-default',
  });
}

Comment: `<?php echo $k ?>` can not be part of parsed HTML..

Comment: I am asking about the HTML which is being appended in DOM..

Comment: it's jquery confirm and id ="confirm"

Comment: A complete example or fiddle will help us understand the issue..Ajax response can be written as string...

Comment: I found the problem is the function when is called in onclick and also has id ="confirmation"   function btn_del_product(id){
 $('#confirm').confirm()
}

<button class="btn btn-danger btn-options" id="confirm" onclick="btn_del_product('<?php echo $k ?>');">

i dont know how can I do it without id,but $('').confirm(); needs an id